# GitHub action is missing the JSON report after the Cypress tests finish

Tags: cypress, github-actions, mochawesome

I am trying to setup a GitHub workflow for executing the Cypress tests in parallel using the [cypress-split](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-split) package to split up the tests. My GitHub repository is also part of a GitHub Enterprise organization (not sure if it is relevant, but wanted to mention it since it might be part of the reason I am having this issue).

The problem is that at the end of the test execution I am getting messages like:

```
Could not find spec results for ./cypress/e2e/demo.cy.ts
```

and there is no test summary data in the workflow:

[image]

I also tried to setup the cypress.config.ts file to use `cypress-mochawesome-reporter`:

```
  reporter: 'cypress-mochawesome-reporter',
  reporterOptions: {
    reporterEnabled: 'cypress-mochawesome-reporter',
    cypressMochawesomeReporterReporterOptions: {
      reportDir: './cypress/reports',
      reportFilename: `results-${process.env.SPLIT_INDEX ?? 0}`,
      saveHtml: false,
      saveJson: true,
      saveAllAttempts: false,
      quiet: true,
    },
  },
```

and during the test execution I can see the following messages:

```
[mochawesome] Report JSON saved to /home/runner/work/demo-project/cypress/reports/html/.jsons/mochawesome_001.json
```

However, after the tests finish I have a step for printing the whole structure of the project:

```
      - name: Verify test project
        if: always()
        run: tree .
```

and I cannot find the final json, even the files from `cypress/reports/html/.jsons/` are no longer there (which would be expected if they were merged into one, but there is no other file).

My project doesn't have the [Cypress github action](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action) whitelisted, so I am starting the project like this:

```
      - name: Install Cypress binary
        run: npx cypress install

      - name: Executing tests 
        run: npm run cypress:run
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue and how to fix this?

Comment: Hello. Have you tried to save the reports in the artifacts and check if they are generated as expected?

Comment: @AlexIzbas yes, but I cannot find the results, I also tried using `tree .` to print the whole project structure after the tests finish and there is a `cypress/reports/html` directory but `cypress/reports/html/.jsons/` is gone even though we see the `[mochawesome] Report JSON saved to /home/runner/work/demo-project/cypress/reports/html/.jsons/mochawesome_001.json` messages after each test suite